# Is the luminous efficiency of a 5000 K incandescent greater than that of a 3000 K bulb?

Tags: temperature, lighting, incandescent, color

The color temperature represents the color of light emitting from an ideal black body, when heated to said temperature in kelvin, and how an incandescent bulb emits light is close to a black body.

Does this mean a 5000 K incandescent bulb has higher filament temperature when powered than a 3000 K? Does a 5000 K incandescent bulb use more power than a 3000 K (EDIT: under the same brightness in lumens)? Does a 5000 K incandescent bulb produce less brightness than a 3000 K when at the same wattage?

Comment: Yes to the first question. But are these class questions? If not, what's the context for these *particular* questions?

Comment: "*Does a 5000K incandescent bulb use more power than a 3000K?*" I advise you to remove this question since it has insufficient to answer it on its own as no constant has been specified (power, lumens, radiant flux, physical dimensions of the filament etc). I assume when you say brightness in your question you mean perceived brightness by human eyes? As opposed to the objective energy in the light?

Comment: There are straight-forward charts and formulas giving the relation between the perceived color and intensity. Since you are asking this question, you should be having these in you textbook or lecture notes.

Comment: Does a red car get better gas mileage than a green car?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson no! Green cars almost always get better gas mileage!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I afraid the analogy is incorrect. I'd say the implicit condition here is "for same intensity", and the the question is legit.

Comment: *Does a 5000 K incandescent bulb use more power than a 3000 K?* That is not a good question. A10 Watt, 5000 K bulb uses **less power** than a 100 Watt, 3000 K lightbulb. But a 1000 Watt, 5000 K bulb will use more power than the same 100 Watt, 3000 K lightbulb. My point: the **power** and **colour temperature** are unrelated!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie They are related if you fix some other parameters, such as intensity

Comment: 100 Watt incandescent lightbulbs (lamps) use 100 Watts, regardless of color temperature. And 50 Watt incandescent lamps use 50 Watts regardless of color temperature etc. But if you take a 50 Watt lamp rated at 3000 K, and over-drive it until the filament is 5000 K, then yes, it will use more power at 5000 K than it does at 3000 K. Of course.

Comment: I get that my questions is probably not specific enough, I can and will work on that. But why I feel that I'm getting some sarcasm through the comments? These are genuine questions. In my head, black body gets different color due to its temperature, and since incandescence light is similar, I would like to know are some relations between the the power, color and brightness.

Comment: @jonk, what do you mean by class questions? Like homework from school? If so, no, they are not. They are just questions in my head and I constantly encounter things in my life that make my think about color temperature and lighting.

Comment: @mkeith, I understand what you're saying. But then it comes to the question—if, under the same wattage & voltage, the 5000K incandescence less bright then a 3000K? It use the same power to heat up the filament, but one is at higher temperature and the other is lower?

Comment: Luminous efficiency (lm/W) will be more than two times higher for a 5000 K bulb versus 3000 K if both are running at the same power. If there would be a cheap enough material to withstand 5000 K, I would say the advances in fluorescent lights and LEDs would have been pushed forwards by decades in the history since the then 5000 K incandescent bulb would have acceptable efficiency, super easy drive and a CRI of 100. LEDs would still take over eventually.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, you never know until you experimented it. I assume a white car will potentially have better gas mileage than a flat black car, since it uses less gas on A/C. If the cars are in space, it probably will have different effects, considering light propulsion/solar sail?

Comment: @winny, it's interesting that luminous efficiency is higher in a 5000K, can you explain why is that? Regarding fluorescent/LED light, I'm discussing the color temperature vs incandescence, and, to my understanding, fluorescent/LED has different behavior and their color temperature are just a "simulation" to color temperature of incandescent.

Comment: @AlienBoy Fair enough. I couldn't tell the context and that's helpful to know when considering a useful answer.

Comment: @AlienBoy Look at the blackbody curves of 5000K vs 3000K. Then note where the sensitivity of human eyes is.

Comment: @AlienBoy What if the white car weighs twice as much as the black car? My point is that you left out critical information, which fortunately you added with your edit.

Comment: As the temperature of the filament goes up, a larger percentage of the radiation coming off of it is visible to the human eye. So the 5000 Kelvin filament should be more efficient than a 3000 Kelvin filament (as Winny said). The reason 3000 Kelvin filaments are not efficient is that much of the energy is radiated away in the infrared spectrum, which we cannot see.

Comment: There is no material that can remain solid at 5000 Kelvin at 1 atmosphere of pressure. Maybe at elevated pressure.

Comment: @mkeith, thank you, those are very good points and helped me understand the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The color temperature represents the color of light emitting from an
> ideal black body, when heated to said temperature in kelvin

Correct. But the *bulb's* color temperature may not coincide exactly with the *filament* temperature. Standard bulb glass absorbs ultraviolet light, which skews the color temperature lower. However we are usually only interested in *visible* light (ie. what the human eye sees) so this has little practical effect except in situations where the proportion of ultraviolet light is important.

> Does this mean a 5000 K incandescent bulb has higher filament
> temperature when powered than a 3000 K?

Not necessarily. An incandescent filament run at 5000 K would produce much more visible light for the same power input as a 3000 K filament, due to the larger proportion of energy radiated in the visible region. But it would quickly burn out.

So how are 5000 K incandescent bulbs a thing? By placing a 'blue' (actually [cyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyan)) filter over the bulb. This increases the color temperature by absorbing longer wavelengths. Here is an example:-

[OSRAM COOL BLUE ADVANCE H7 5000K](https://www.osram.asia/ecat/COOL%20BLUE%20ADVANCE-Halogen%20headlight%20lamps-Car%20lighting-Automotive/asia/en/GPS01_2980013/ZMP_4056737/)

[image]

This bulb puts out *less* visible light than an equivalent unfiltered bulb of the same wattage.

Now you may ask, what is the point of making a headlight bluer if it reduces the light output? Wouldn't that just make the road ahead harder to see? Not necessarily. Most of the human eye has a higher density of rods (monochrome sensors, more sensitive to green light) than cones (color sensors), and the rods are more sensitive at low light. 5000 K is closer to daylight, so objects appear closer to their expected colors than they would in 'warmer' light. Filtering out excessive red light makes the *perceived* image sharper and easier to see, particularly in the peripheral area that is important for driving safety.

Comment: +1 for finding an *actual* 500K incandescent! Blue filter (lowering efficiency) is indeed the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! With everyone's discussion, I now know my question is flawed and where the flaw are. There's much more factors to consider and you did point me at the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you took some incandescent light bulb and applied a voltage to it such that its filament glows at 3000K and you measured the power consumed by this light bulb;
then, with this same light bulb, you adjust the voltage until its filament glows at 5000K and again measure the power consumed;
then yes you'll almost certainly observe that this particular bulb consumes more power at 5000K than it does at 3000K.

But you'd be ignoring the fact that at 5000K the bulb was also emitting more light than it was at 3000K.

So the really useful measurement here would be the efficiency of the light bulb - how does its light output change as a function of power consumed at those different color-temperature values?
I don't have the data, but my intuition says that at lower color-temperatures the light bulb will be turning a greater fraction of its power consumed into heat instead of light, resulting in lower efficiency at lower color-temperatures.

But then you'd also have to consider if the heat output of the light bulb is actually useful too. I've read anecdotes where traffic-lights were 'upgraded' from incandescent bulbs to LEDs - but this was in an area which sees significant snowfall during winter. The old incandescent bulbs warmed the traffic lights enough to mostly keep the snow melted while the new LEDs did not - resulting in the 'upgraded' lights no longer being visible...

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by brhans, which is *mostly* correct, I will mention that an incandescent bulb draws far more power at lower light levels, due to the lower filament resistance. That's why some say it's not worth it to shut the light off when exiting a room and coming back 10seconds later. As others have stated, though, the question does not give adequate information. If we presume the same quantity of photons emitted from a linear source, we ought factor in the photon energy based on light wavelength. Tables exist for that.

Answer (score 0):

What filament material can remain solid at 5000K for long enough to make a useful incandescent bulb?

The nearest I can think of is an old-style photographic flashbulb, where the filament is magnesium. And the answer is, it uses less  electrical power because the main energy source is the burning magnesium itself. Of course, it only lasts for 20 milliseconds or so...

Comment: Now I understand that a 5000 K color temperature bulb isn't actually heated to 5000 kelvin, then I'm curious what's the usual filament temperature of a 5000 K incandescent bulb? Is that quite far away from 5000 K?

Comment: It'll be around the same as the (clear) 3000K bulb. There's a reason incandescents stop at 3000K, except for photoflood bulbs used in photo studios ... at 3200K their life expectancy is ... 3 to 20 hours.